# git subtree pull with missing directories

Tags: git, git-subtree

I've got an existing git repo that I want to import a subset of into another git repo.  Initially I added in the whole repo:

```
git remote add -f coda-oss_remote https://github.com/mdaus/coda-oss.git
git subtree add --prefix externals/coda-oss coda-oss_remote master --squash
```

This worked fine.  Then I wanted to get rid of some of the unneeded directories (necessary for a variety of reasons).  This was actually simpler than I expected; I just removed them similar to this:

```
git rm -r externals/coda-oss/modules/drivers/pcre
```

In subsequent pulls...

```
git subtree pull --prefix externals/coda-oss coda-oss_remote master --squash
```

git was smart and just pulled in updates to that other repo and didn't try to recreate the removed directories.  Everything worked exactly like I wanted it to.

The other day was the first time that I've tried to pull when there's been a modification to one of the files in a directory that I've removed in this second repo.  I got a merge conflict because git saw that the file had been modified in the original repo but wasn't present in my repo.  This was simple enough to resolve - I just had to do another 'git rm' of the file - but I'd like this process to be something I can script up and automatically merge everything in.

Is there a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do or at least an automatic way to do it so I can script it (I could parse the merge conflicts and run the 'git rm' off of that I suppose).